# Downloaded PyCharm but doesnt have support for django/flask?

Tags: python, pycharm

Heard that pycharm has a very good support for django/flask, but cant find any support by it.

Comment: Have you tried to create a project by using one of these frameworks? Or search the web about? Maybe you should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have downloaded the community edition of pycharm. Try downloading Professional version of PyCharm. It has support for Cython, AppEngine, Django, Flask etc. Check out full list of feature comparision here.
[Pycharm Pro vs Community comparision](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Answer (score 1):

Below you will see the types of projects supported by pycharm professional. I've personally used Flask, ant it works great.

[image: New Project Window]